# How to get Canon printers to work with Arch Linux?

Tags: drivers, arch-linux, cups

I am trying to setup a Canon MF4412 printer on my Arch Linux desktop.

I followed the [official guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS) in setting up a CUPS server/client as well as installing the cndrvcups-lb driver package.

However, my CUPS server is still unable to detect the printer. My best guess is there is a problem with the drivers.

Are there any solutions available?

Answer (score 5):

Install the `gutenprint` package and then try adding it through the CUPS administration interface (`http://localhost:631/admin`). This worked for me for another Canon printer.